# Client Side ReactJS with Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, lumen

Im planning to implement my new project using ReactJS (Client Side) and Lumen/Laravel(backend).

I have few questions,

- Can I achieve routing with just client side scripting?
- how can I separate the logic (components) into multiple files and bring it
  together on rending (without NPM)?
- what are the best practices when using reactjs for just client side rending.

Comment: uh, have you checked on [google](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/reactjs-with-laravel) yet..? your question feels too broad.. especially the last one..

Comment: the reason for last comment is to know if there is any industry best practice of arranging files like what we have for serverside (MVC/HMVC etc). Additionally, searching google comes with enormous results, which may not be always a recommended path. Would love to hear from experienced hands-on devs on this aspect

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

You can use something like `react-router` to handle all your frontend routing. I will generally have a catch all route in laravel for all frontend handled routes, and a seperate api route file for api requests.

[react-router](http://react-router.now.sh)

Example laravel route file:

```
// -- api stuff and thangs --
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::get('me', 'UserController@index');
    Route::post('me', 'UserController@update');

    // 404 just for API sutff
    Route::any('{any}', function() {
        abort(404);
    })->where('any', '.*');
});

// -- all the frontend --
Route::any('{any}', function() {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**Second question**

Browser support for modules is really lacking at the time of writing. You will almost definitely need to use webpack or browseify to be able to keep your files seperate. Learning one or the other is worth it, and will save you a lot of headaches.

**Third question**

This is way too broad for Stackoverflow. You will need to start with the react docs, and by following the docs, you will be following best practices for using react as a client side renderer.